# What is the default behavior for a mousedown?

Tags: jquery

I came across some code that explicitly prevents the default behavior for a mousedown event. I'm wondering what the default behavior might be for a mousedown and why you would want to prevent it.

```
   .on('mousedown.minicolors', '.minicolors-grid', function (event) {
      var target = $(this); 
      event.preventDefault();
      $(document).data('minicolors-target', target);
      move(target, event, true);
   })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior depends upon what the object is.

We could answer more specifically if you showed the relevant HTML that goes with the code and perhaps a little more of the code so we could see what objects the code is acting on.

In addition, calling `preventDefault()` doesn't hurt anything even if there is no default behavior.

Comment: Mouse _down_ doesn't submit a form or toggle a checkbox - you have to also have a mouse _up_ on the same element (where the down + up results in a click event). That is, if you hold the mouse down and drag the mouse off the button before releasing, there will be no click event and no submit/toggle.

Comment: @nnnnnn - ok fine.  I removed the specific examples.

Comment: In  this case it's $(document).on('mousedown.minicolors', '.minicolors-grid', function (event) {...} The .minicolors-grid element selector is just a square div with a color rainbow grid in it. The effect of the mousedown is to move the color picker in the grid to the place where you clicked.

Comment: @Steve - then the `preventDefault()` is probably not doing anything.

Comment: `In addition, calling preventDefault() doesn't hurt anything even if there is no default behavior.`

it does hurt , https://github.com/reakit/reakit/issues/432#issuecomment-534218058

`preventDefault` disables us from using `:active` class